# Matching rows: Do I need a cursor? (SQL Server 2005)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, cursor, set, grouping

I have 2 tables, call them G and T, on which I am selecting records based upon matching on a number of fields.

```
SELECT
    g.ID, t.ID
FROM
    g JOIN t
        ON (g.Field1 = t.Field1
            AND g.Field2 = t.Field2
            AND .... )
```

There can be more than one record that matches each side  e.g. rows t1 and t2 are identical on the fields used for matching, as are g1 and g2 and they match each other, giving

```
t1    g1
t1    g2
t2    g1
t2    g2
```

(the actual ids are ints, but you get the idea)

What we want is for each T record to match to only one G record (we don't care which as long as they are *different* ones) e.g. either of

```
t1    g1       
t2    g2
```

OR

```
t1    g2       
t2    g1
```

would be acceptable, but NOT

```
t1    g1       
t2    g1
```

And not both resultsets - we only want the 2 rows total (in this example).

There might be (say) 30,000 rows in the initial selection from each table. Not everything will have a match, this is fine.

Can this be done set-wise or do I have to use a cursor?

EDITED in response to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) to assign some arbitrary identifiers to do the matching on:

```
;With TOrdered as (
    select ID,Field1,Field2,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Field1,Field2 ORDER BY ID) as rn
    from T
), GOrdered as (
    select ID,Field1,Field2,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Field1,Field2 ORDER BY ID) as rn
    from G
)
SELECT
    g.ID, t.ID
FROM
    GOrdered g
      JOIN
    TOrdered t
    ON (g.Field1 = t.Field1
        AND g.Field2 = t.Field2
        AND g.rn = t.rn )
```

(If there are mismatches on counts between the two tables, some rows will not appear in the final result at all - but you haven't really indicated whether they should or not, or how they should be dealt with)

Comment: ah, I recall doing this sort of thing before - thanks for reminding me!